# Pandas: Looking to create a multiple nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas

Here is what I am looking to generate:

```
{A: {1: [1,2], 2: [2,5]},
 B: {3: [1,4], 4: [7,8]}}
```

Here is the df:

```
id sub_id
A  1
A  2
B  3
B  4
```

and I have the following array:

```
[[1,2],
[2,5],
[1,4],
[7,8]]
```

So far, I have the following code:

```
sub_id_array_dict = dict(zip(df['sub_id'].to_list(), arrays))
```

this results in the following dictionary:

```
{1: [1,2],
 2: [2,5],
 3: [1,4],
 4: [7,8]}
```

Now, I feel like i've gone down the wrong path as I'm not sure how to get roll it up to the `id` level.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are there actually dots at the of the letters in your dataframe?

Comment: No, sorry about that. Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple loop this can be done like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

sub_id_array_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for i, s, a in zip(df['id'].to_list(), df['sub_id'].to_list(), arrays):
    sub_id_array_dict[i][s] = a
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Now, I should have included this in my original question but do you think this solution will scale well? My actual dataset contains 600K ids and 100M sub_id. I can ask this in a new question if you'd like.

Comment: @MadhavThaker, for such numbers a loop in Python as shown here is a bad approach. I think this is something different so you should create a new question.

Comment: Ok, will do, thank you.